# Accessing CKRecord values in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, ckrecord

I'm trying to access a certain field in my CKRecord, which I know exists, but when I do so, I get "unexpectedly found nil".

Here's the syntax:

```
var prevFact = birdFacts[0].value(forKey: "sortingDate") as! Int
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you been able to find the solution?